# ArCore Augmented Images image not visible

Tags: android, arcore, android-augmented-reality, sceneform

I am implementing the new augmenting images recognition feature of the `ArCore`. The recognition of my database images is working fine and a video start playing when they get recognized. However i was wondering if there is any listener that is called when the image is not visible any more in the scene so that i can stop and hide the video of that image. Currently in my implementation the video stays to the same position in the scene where the image was recognized even if i remove the physical image.

Answer (score 2):

Check the current [TrackingMethod](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/AugmentedImage.TrackingMethod) for the AugmentedImage when the TrackingState is Tracking. When the image is in view of the camera the TrackingMethod is FULL_TRACKING ,else it will be in LAST_KNOWN_POSE. If you are using the sample augmentedImages example, it will be like this in AugmentedImageActvity.java -

```
 private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) 
 {
 .
   for (AugmentedImage augmentedImage : updatedAugmentedImages) 
   {
   .
     switch (augmentedImage.getTrackingState())
     {
     .
       case TRACKING: if(augmentedImage.getTrackingMethod()==AugmentedImage.TrackingMethod.FULL_TRACKING) {
                        //Enable VideoNode 
                      }
                      else{
                        //Disable VideoNode / Pause MediaPlayer /detach node
                      }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `public TrackingState getTrackingState ()` if it returns `public static final TrackingState STOPPED` you can stop your video or destroy however you want. For more details you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/AugmentedImage#getTrackingState())

Comment: I thought of that in the beginning as well but the tracking state of the image is still `TRACKING` even if i remove the image from the scene, so `STOPPED` is not called as i would expect it to do.

Comment: Have you checked [AugmentedImage](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmentedimage/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageActivity.java) sample. This should work exactly like you wanted.

Comment: My code is based on that but as i mentioned the tracking state is not working as expecting

Comment: Can you share your code where you check for tracking so i can try to reproduce the error?